# Find property with certain type and return it

Tags: c#

I have an object from a class (let's call it `classA`), and I know that it has a property object from another class (`classB`). How can I find the object with type `classB` and return it (with all it's values)?

```
//classA:

int id;
string name;
classB subItem;

//classB:

int randomNumber;
string answerOfLife;
```

I wrote this function that search all the properties of `classA` for the one with propertyType `classB`. I can find the property, but then I'm stuck with a `PropertyInfo` object, where I really want a `classB` object with all the values.

```
classB tempObject = (classB) classAObject.FindPropertyType("classB");
```

Function:

```
internal BaseDataObject FindPropertyType(string strMember) {

        foreach (PropertyInfo prop in this.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            if (prop.PropertyType.Name.ToString().ToLower() == strMember.ToLower())
                //This is where it goes wrong!
                return (BaseDataObject) prop.GetValue(this,null);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

the `prop.GetValue(this,null)` returns the parent (`classA`) object instead of the desired `classB` object.

Comment: Does `ClassB` inherit `(BaseDataObject)`?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov yes, both `classA` and `classB` inherit from the abstrac class `BaseDataObject`.

Comment: @CodeCaster : I don't get the `classB` object. I return the original `classA` object instead.

Comment: Very unclear from the description. Please show an actual compiling example and explain the problem properly.

Comment: @CodeCaster I improved my question (or so I hope).

Comment: This code does not return the containing class (i.e. `this`) as you claim it does, it returns the found property's value. You do realize you're querying on _type_ name and calling it with _member_ name? Again, please create an example that compiles and demonstrates the problem properly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84381/discussion-between-jordumus-and-codecaster).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've updated my answer to use generics, see my previous use of `is` and `as` below which was upvoted before:

Use [Generics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx).  It will make this logic much more flexible and reusable:

We need to replace all calls to `BaseDataObject` to `T` in your internal method, so I modified FindPropertyByType:

```
public class BaseDataObject
    {
        internal T FindPropertyType<T>(string strMember)
        {
            var type = this.GetType();
            var props = type.GetProperties();
            foreach (PropertyInfo prop in props)
            {
                if (prop.PropertyType.Name.ToString().ToLower() == strMember.ToLower())
                    //This is where it goes wrong!
                    return (T)prop.GetValue(this, null);
            }
            return default(T);
        }

    }
```

The `default(T)` will return the default value for the type of T, which in your case is Null.

Now, whenever you need this method you can specify which type you want, like so:

```
B tempObject = a.FindPropertyType<B>("B");
```

additionally, this should work too:

```
var myId = a.FindPropertyType<int>("id");
```

**Previous Answer Below**

If I read your question correctly you can use the `is` keyword ([MSDN Doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw.aspx))

```
if( someProperty is classB)
   //do something
else
   //do something different
```

or you can use `as` keyword([MSDN doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx)) which will return null if the object is the one you are casting:

```
private classB getPropAsClassB(someProperty)
{
    return someProperty as classB;
}

var myProp = getPropAsClassB(someProp); //will be null if it isn't a classB object
```

Comment: Thank you, I added some information. I can find the right object, but I can't return it. I need the object (with it's values) from `classB` and I only got that `PropertyInfo` object atm.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have list of objects :

```
List<object> objects; // all types of objects here include classA, int, string etc
```

Then you can do :

```
classB tempObject = (objects.FirstOrDefault(o => o is classA) as ClassA).subItem;
```

If objects doesn't contain any instances of ClassA this will throw Nullreference exception when we try to access the 'subItem' property...